# How to use the same form with different form title in APEX

Tags: forms, edit, apex, create-table

I have 2 buttons one which creates new row and other which edits the row. I have been using the same form. I would like to change the title of the form such that it displays "create new row" when create button is clicked and "Edit row" when edit button is clicked. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable into title field:

[image: Title variable]

and initialise this variable with a pre-rendering plsql procedure